# X-application-context-header is not being passed to httpHeaders Map in openshift/liberty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I added `management.server.add-application-context-header=true` to `application.properties` in `Springboot(2.0.3.RELEASE)/spring(5.0.7.RELEASE)/camel(2.22.0)` app  and i deployed to my local liberty and when i make a sample rest call and checked whether response headers has the `X-application-context-header` in headers or not. It does have but when i deploy the same app in `openshift/liberty` the `X-application-context-header` is not getting passed in HTTPHeaders. Any thoughts on what could be the reason.